# how we can update child datalist's options which is present inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am new on jquery , I am not understanding what I am doing wrong . I want append and delete options of datalist. datalist is present inside in div please see my code :

```
<input type="text" id="deloption" name="deloption" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;width:100px;" placeholder="del Options">
<input type="text" id="addoption" name="addoption" style="margin-bottom:8px;padding:3px;width:100px;" placeholder="Add Options">
<div class="test" id="combobox"><input type="text" name="example" list="exampleList">
<datalist id="exampleList">
    <option value="A">
    <option value="B">
</datalist></div>
```

jquery code : 
for add an option :

```
$('#'+Gid).children()[1].append("<option value='" + document.getElementById("addoption").value + "'>");
```

for del an option :

```
$('#'+Gid).children().find("datalist option[value="+document.getElementById('deloption').value+"]").remove();
```

Gid is dynamic id of div . there will be no. of div's .

Comment: what is the value of `deloption` ?

Comment: We have no idea on which context you call these snippets. On any event? If so, is this event hanlder fired? Etc...  One thing, `$('#'+Gid).children()[1]` should be `$('#'+Gid).children().eq(1)`

Comment: @Noman : value enter by user at run time and that will be get by jquery function call .

Comment: please add complete code of jquery

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create an option like so:

```
var myDatalist = document.getElementById("exampleList");
myDatalist.add(new Option(text,value));
```

and then remove it like so:

```
$("#exampleList option[value="value"]).remove();
```

Comment: Why would this been better?  Any link about DOM node `add()` method?

Comment: @TheWandererr : that is working and I did it . but I want access datalist from div which is parent of datalist , So please can you help me for that .

Comment: @A.Wolff I didnt say it is better. i think its just cleaner and easier to understand than adding it with a option tag.

Comment: I'm still curious to see any link regarding `add()` method?

Comment: Can we do that from parent div  ?

Comment: Well, but you are calling it on DOM node... And jQuery prototype `add()` method has nothing to do with expected behaviour here. It doesn't append new node in DOM, it append element in matched set, returning new set. Quite well documented, indeed... ;) I'm sorry but i have to downvote this answer, could mislead futur readers otherwise